# Changing css for portion of span

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a solution to highlight the best models in a table ( not a html table). Problem is that each model is comprised of several trims. So for price, for instance, I show a range from low to top price for that model, like $50.000 - $ 60000.

I can highlight the whole span tag that has that information, with script below, but I would like to highlight just the lower price, ie, $50.000., without messing up my whole set up.

For clarification, in the case of the first value in the variable 'best' below (92.9), the span tags that contains that value (3rd from top on the li ) also contains 113.9. I want that ONLY 92.9 is highlighted. The 113.9 should be left as is.

I know that I have to add a tag somehow for those cases that I want to highlight, but I fell short on how properly separate the best values.

Please see fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/SnYWL/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var best = ['92.9','74.9','17','197','4.1','106','774'];//simplified
    var order = [5, 8, 12, 14, 15, 16, 19];
for(var i=0; i<7 ;i++){

$("#modinfo li span:nth-child(" + order[i] + ")").each(function(){
  var best_val=$(this).text();
if(best_val.indexOf(best[i]) > -1){
    $(this).css('color','#33cc00');
}
});
}
});
</script>
```

The table is made up of a series of li elements, like example below:

```
    <ul id="modinfo">

<li>
    <span class="z1">i10</span>
    <span class="z2">3</span>
    <span class="z1">92.9-113.9</span>
            <span class="z5">5.2-5.7</span>
            <span class="z6">86.4-101.5</span>
    <span class="z1">ilim</span>
    <span class="z2">6</span>
    <span class="z1">69</span>      
            <span class="z2">4.7 a 5.8</span>
            <span class="z1">111</span>
    <span class="z1">5</span>
    <span class="z2">225</span>
            </li>

........
```

Comment: What do you want to highlight? Seems like you already done that.

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking:**
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry guys. In those cases when there are 2 values in the span, I want to highlight ONLY the target value, not both. In the case of 92.9 I want only that to be highlighted not 92.9 and 113.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about replace the target value with styled span?

Like

```
$(this).html(best_val.replace(best[i], "<span style='color:#33cc00'>" + best[i] + "</span>"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clxy/SnYWL/1/)